# GitHub Pages can't see my project correctly

Tags: reactjs, json, github-pages, vite

I've tried to publish the project on GitHub Pages a couple of times but failed. This is my first React project.

I don't know if it's because of a bad project structure:

[image: Project Structure]

... or if I'm doing something wrong with GIT itself. I am asking for help, or for some good and up-to-date guide on YT or forum.

When I just publish a page to GitHub Pages, it's just the background, nothing else. I also used the guides, but at best only the Header component loaded. Routing was not working and dynamically generated items from `.json` file were not loading.

**UPDATE**
Old repo is no longer available. There is a new version of it [here](https://github.com/Moorroww/FrontEndMentor-DevJobs)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please post enough code and supporting information so that someone can provide help.  This site is for answering specific questions , and currently the scope of this question is too broad with the provided information.  Sounds like the question is more like "how do i fix my routing issues and dynamic code generation."
(show the code that is not working properly)

Comment: Here is the [repo link](https://github.com/Moorroww/FrontEndMentor-DevJobs). Everything is fine with functionality when I run dev server.

Comment: Here is the link to the JSON file directly  for someone to look at -->
https://github.com/Moorroww/FrontEndMentor-DevJobs/blob/main/public/data.json

Comment: Hi! I see [you tried out](https://github.com/Moorroww/FrontEndMentor-DevJobs/actions/runs/5426327530/jobs/9868237699) my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76591460/15167500) and [it worked](https://github.com/Moorroww/FrontEndMentor-DevJobs/actions/runs/5426327530/jobs/9868237699)! Now you just need to change the static URL of your app from `./` to `./{repo-name}` so that the CSS and JS files are fetched from `github.io/{repo-name}/assets` instead of `github.io/assets` on your page. I updated my steps with it.

Comment: **Avoid referencing it from the `src` folder!** Move the `favicon-32x32.png` file to the `public` folder and simply reference it as if the website were already running; Vite will take care of everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Github Pages

GitHub Pages can display static webpages. Therefore, you will need the production version of your code, which you can build and upload to the [dist](https://github.com/Moorroww/FrontEndMentor-DevJobs/tree/main/dist) folder of your repository.

#### Solution: automatically build production and deploy

Need configure your Github Action for this repository.

##### Step # 1

Need to define your base on Vite.

```js
// vite.config.js

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/reponame/' : '/',
    // Other build configuration options...
  },
})
```

Or can use relative default path - i prefer to it for Github Page -

```js
// vite.config.js

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    base: './',
    // Other build configuration options...
  },
})
```

##### Step # 2

Generate a new file to `/.github/workflows` as `deploy.yml`.

- use [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) for can run actions
- use [actions/setup-node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) for can use node.js and npm
- use [peaceiris/actions-gh-pages](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages) for can update Github Page

Add configuration:

```yaml
name: Deploy to GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./dist
```

#### Step # 3

Commit and push your new `deploy.yml`.

#### Step # 4

Visit your GitHub repository in your browser, then click on the "Actions" tab. Here, you should see the workflow labeled "Deploy to GitHub Pages" that starts after the push. Wait until the workflow successfully completes.

It's generate your production version and deploy it to Github Pages.

#### Step # 5

Open your Github Pages static application:

`https://<github-username>.github.io/<repository-name>/`

#### Summary

Now, if you make changes to the source code (dev) and push them, GitHub Actions will compile your production code and update your GitHub Pages site after a short period of time.

Comment: Ty for your solution, however I did it differently.. I created a [new repository](https://github.com/Moorroww/fin-devjobs) and also I created a [gh-pages branch](https://github.com/Moorroww/fin-devjobs/tree/gh-pages), pasted the necessary files, etc. Then I changed the paths as you wrote and the site now "works". However, cards fetched from the `data.json` file still do not show up. And I can't really change the `base: "./"` in `vite.config.js` to different path because the page shows an error and won't load. So there is still a thing with fetching data from file and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: You referred to `/data.json` in `CardsSection.jsx`. **Try using `./data.json` instead.** By the way, I usually create a function in all my apps that generates the URL corresponding to the appropriate root path. Let's call this example function `getUrl()`, which takes `data.json` as a parameter and returns the file `http://example.com/rootfolder/data.json` if the app is running from the `rootfolder`.

Comment: Yes, I also support the separation of the production code running on GitHub Pages from the source code. It makes it clearer what you will be running, and you did a great job with it!

Comment: The `/data.json` to `./data.json` thing fixed the issue. I also moved logos to public folder and changed all logos paths in `data.json` file to `./logos/{svg-name}` (there was an issue with logos loading). However the CardDetailed component doesn't show when the Card component is clicked :/

Comment: I fixed it, there was worng path in `navigate()` function. Ty sm for all the help here :)