# Github Pages only shows me a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

My repository: https://github.com/Alperenkarslix/website
My website: https://alperenkarslix.github.io/website/

I can not figure out why my `GitHub pages` can’t load any of my source files. The files I want to load are in the `src folder`. Everything works as it should on localhost. It only loads `index.html` which is a white blank screen, I don't have anything coded in this file. I’ve seen a few similar posts about this issue but have not found any solution.

I have installed the `gh-pages module` through `npm` and done “npm run deploy”; this created my `gh-pages branch.` I’ve updated my `package.json` with the needed information.

I hosted this website before on `Github Pages` at this domain with no issues. It appears that `Github pages` and the process has changed since then and I can’t get it to run now.

I added this code in `package.json:`

```
"homepage" : "https://alperenkarslix.github.io/",
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

and I have a `gh-pages branch` in my repository
I use this command in terminal
`npm run deploy`, which works and it say Published however I still can't see my pages.

Comment: Please note that [providing a link to your site is not sufficient](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428). Paste your code here as text so as to make a [mre].

Comment: Notice that your website tries to load the static files from the following link: `https://alperenkarslix.github.io/static/js/main.3a3c4f11.js`. You need to add `/website` after `github.io` in order to load it up correctly - `https://alperenkarslix.github.io/website/static/js/main.3a3c4f11.js`.

Comment: You cannot directly deploy a react app to github pages. You can use something like [react-gh-pages](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages) to directly deploy react app to github pages.

Comment: I already created it using the instructions in the link you gave, but it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe can help you: [How to host your static page with Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76591460/15167500) - StackOverflow answer

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

Need to define your base on Vite.

```js
// vite.config.js

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/reponame/' : '/',
    // Other build configuration options...
  },
})
```

Or can use relative default path - i prefer to it for Github Page -

```js
// vite.config.js

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    base: './',
    // Other build configuration options...
  },
})
```

After deploy, open your Github Pages static application:

`https://<github-username>.github.io/<repository-name>/`

#### More information

- [Github Pages Quickstart](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/quickstart) - Github Docs
- [Deploy static Vite app](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html) - Vite Docs
- [Github Pages can't see my project correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590443/github-pages-cant-see-my-project-correctly/76591460#76591460) - StackOverflow answer
- [Github Pages configure publishing source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) - Github Docs
- [Vite Deploy Demo](https://github.com/sitek94/vite-deploy-demo) - Github Repository

Answer (score 1):

```json
"homepage": "https://alperenkarslix.github.io/website", // Your URL
"scripts": {
  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d out" // Change 'build' to 'out' if you're using Next.js
}
```

Comment: Github Pages its working

Comment: I use Node.js but i solve the problem thank you!

Answer (score 0):

please try replacing the homepage key in the package.json from

```
"homepage": "https://alperenkarslix.github.io/"
```

to

```
"homepage": "https://alperenkarslix.github.io/website"
```

here website refers to your app name.

Comment: i changed the code as you mentioned and redeployed but still the same

Comment: please use basename="/website" in the Router component at line 11 in app.js